# Storing current index number as a variable - Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm attempting to create a bash script that updates the timestamps of files in alphabetical order. The script works but seems to be passing it's flags to the `touch` command used within. After my `getopts` `while` loop, I've added the following: `shift $((OPTIND-1))` to update my index. It took me a while but I realize that the problem with my code is that I later initialize my `for` loop at index 0 instead of the current index number (i.e, `for ((i=0; i<=${#file[-1]}; i++))`). How do I store my current index number as a variable so that I can tell my `for` loop to start there?

```
#!/bin/bash

file=($@)
reverse=false
delay=0 #In seconds
verbose=false

sort() {
    touch "${file[$i]}"
    if [ $verbose = true ]; then
        echo "${file[$i]}"
    fi
    sleep $delay
}

while getopts "rvt:" opts; do
    case ${opts} in
        r) reverse=true;;
        v) verbose=true;;
        t) delay=${OPTARG};;
        ?) exit;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ $reverse = false ]; then
    for ((i=0; i<=${#file[-1]}; i++)); do
        sort
    done
else
    for ((i=${#file[@]}-1; i>=0; i--)); do
        sort
    done
fi
```

Comment: If you put `file=($@)` after `shift`, then you don't need to store index, as it always starts at 0.

Comment: @Philippe Thank you! Such a simple solution but it now works perfectly! I would still be curious to know how to store an index number as a variable but this is a very elegant solution.

Comment: You can try `$((OPTIND-1))` as zero-based index, ot just $OPTIND as one-based index.

Comment: You should double-quote `$@` (and maybe some other variable & parameter references) to avoid trouble with arguments that contain spaces or some other funny characters: `file=("$@")`. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out problems like this.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson. I've installed ShellCheck on my system so it should be pretty easy to use going forward.